# View does not cover full screen when Xcode with Swift without storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, ios-simulator

I am creating an app without storyboard; I removed the storyboard file. The app runs fine, but the output from the simulator is off; somehow I am not able to use the full screen of the iPhone.

iPhone simulator example where top and bottom is blank:
[image: Iphone simulator example where top and bot is blank]

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions){
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = myViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
}
```

What is missing here?

Comment: Try setting LaunchScreen.storyboard in the Xcode Project Settings. I assume you have deleted it too, add it and set it, and check if this works for you

Comment: Did you create auto layout constraints for myViewController?

You can also use this as reference: https://www.raywenderlich.com/6004856-building-an-app-with-only-code-using-auto-layout

E.g. they used the bounds from the coordinateSpace of the scene to set the frame of the window instead of the bounds of UIScreen as you did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come across the same problem when the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file was removed. Now the system seems not sure of the screen size and hence the problem occurs. Please try adding the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` if you have removed it.

Comment: I added a dummy storyboard file, it works!!. But I originally have storyboard, I removed the entry point and have the same problem, then I removed the storyboard completely, not sure why the first time with story was failing.. Any way Thanks!